# Set Default Values on Fields With Workflow

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-on-prem

Is there a way to programatically set the default value of a column in SP2013?  Here is my use case scenario:

I have a project site collection.  A form is used at the top level site to create a site using a specific site template via a workflow.  The site is created with a custom document library with some fields [Project, Project Manager, Et].  These values will be the same for every file in the document library.  Is there a way to set default values via a workflow so that each time a file is uploaded to this document library, the information is already populated?

I am using SP2013 OnPrem.

Comment: You can create a workflow when item is added and then fill default value. Or by developing an event receiver when an itemcreated.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thank you for your response!  Unf I don't have access to farm for the farm solution & we'll be upgrading to SPO soon.  I guess I didn't explain it well.  I'm worried that a workflow for every doc that is uploaded is taxing.  The form creates a new project site based on the entries in the form.  I wanted to know if there was a way to SET the default values automatically instead of having to go to every project site's library settings & setting the column default values there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating custom fields, you can set Default Value, just edit these fields in Library Settings:

[image]

- or you can use PowerShell with [Set-PnPDefaultColumnValues](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpdefaultcolumnvalues?view=sharepoint-ps).
- or with classic SharePoint PowerShell:

> ```
> $w = Get-SPWeb http://localhost  
> $l = $w.GetListFromUrl("/Lists/SampleList2/AllItems.aspx")  
> $f = $l.Fields["First Name"]  
> $f.DefaultValue = "my default name" 
> $f.Update()
> ```

Comment: Hi Zdenek, thanks for your reply.  Yes I know about changing in Library Settings.  I don't want to manually go in & set the values each time a site is created via the workflow. I'm wondering if there is way to set the default values via a workflow when the document library is created.  I can't run any PowerShell scripts as I don't have access to the server to do so.